# React: Updated non-state variables in useEffect show old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The useeffect hook shows older values of a non-state variable that I am trying to access there. The non-state variable's value is being updated just before the state variable set method is called. What I am doing wrong here?

```
function Clock(){
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  let custom = 1;
  const clickHandler = () => {
    custom = 0;
    setCount(1);
  }
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    alert(custom);
  })
  return (<div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
    </div>);
}

function tick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
tick();
```

The alert still prints the old value of the variable `custom`
Why is useEffect unable to get the up-to-date value of the variable?

Comment: What are you expecting it to print, question is unclear without that piece of information.

Comment: I am expecting it to print 0 which is the updated value of the custom variable instead of the old value of 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variables you declare outside of the state are created each time your component is re-rendered.
If you want to keep the value you may chose either two ways - to keep them in state or in ref (useRef hook).
The rule is quite simple - if change should cause re-render - your option is state. If not (for example, you want to know how many times a button has been clicked) - useRef is your best friend.

```
function Clock(){
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const custom = useRef(1);
  const clickHandler = () => {
    custom.current = 0;
    setCount(1);
  }
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    alert(custom.current);
  })
  return (<div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
    </div>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise explanation. I did not realize that local variables are re-created in case of a re-render of the functional component.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `useEffect` needs to understand when `count` changes.
2. Your click handler just keeps setting the state to `1`.
3. You don't do anything with your `custom` variable.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Clock(){

  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  // Increment the count state
  function clickHandler() {
    const newState = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;
    setCount(newState);
  }

  // The effect checks to see if `count` has changed
  // and logs (alerts) it
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );

}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Check the useEffect. The value of the custom variable is printed in useEffect. Don't remove it from your code. What I want to know is why it keeps printing 1 instead of 0 which is the updated value of the custom variable.
The state variable count is just being used to trigger the useEffect hook. It has no other inherent use in this code. The custom variable's value is what I am interested in

Comment: See point 2) . Your click handler just keeps setting the state to 1.

Comment: clickHandler is only called when the button is clicked. Setting the state variable to some other value so that the useEffect hook can be triggered. That's the only use for the state variable here. I want to understand why useEffect hook takes old value of custom variable as current value? Help me understand the flow please.

Comment: It's really unclear what you need. Are you just trying to toggle between 0 and 1 when the button is clicked?

Comment: yes, I want the alert inside useEffect to print the up-to-date value of the custom variable. Why is it not happening and what can I do to make it happen?

Comment: Just adjust the state to toggle between 0 and 1. I've updated my answer.

Comment: the problem is I don't want to use the state variable. I am interested in the non state variable (this is not my real code and that is much more complex than this). I just want to understand why useEffect falls to get the latest value for the custom variable. By removing that variable from your answer, you are avoiding the real point behind my question. Printing and alternating between 1s and 0s is not a big deal and I can do that without any help using state variables.

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect).